# SQL Server indexed view matching of views with joins not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, materialized-views, indexed-view

Does anyone have experience of when SQL Server 2008 R2 is able to automatically match indexed view (also known as materialized views) that contain joins to a query?

For example the view

```
select dbo.Orders.Date, dbo.OrderDetails.ProductID
from dbo.OrderDetails
join dbo.Orders on dbo.OrderDetails.OrderID = dbo.Orders.ID
```

Cannot automatically be matched to the same exact query. When I select directly from this view `with (noexpand)` I actually get a much faster query plan that does a scan on the clustered index of the indexed view. Can I get SQL Server to do this matching automatically? I have quite a few queries and views and I do not want to reference the indexed view manually each time because I am using an OR mapper.

I am on enterprise edition of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Edit: I found the solution. SQL Server 2008 R2 does not match indexed views with more than 2 joins automatically. Probably it would slow down the optimization process too much.

**Edit 2: Reviewing this 2 years after the question was created by me, I don't think my conclusion was correct. Materialized view matching is a very fragile process with no clear rules that I could find over the years.**

Certainly, the following play a role:

- Number of joins
- Presence of a predicate
- Join order, both in the view and in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little fuzzy on exactly what your question is; but I think this will give you what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181151.aspx

There are a lot of strange, arbitrary-seeming conditions that limit when SQL Server will use a view index in a query. This page documents them for SQL Server 2008.